# get ImageUrl from ImageButton before Postback-event in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i'm using a featured bar in my webpage.
This bar contains 6 pictures, and all 6 of these elements are ImageButtons.
When the page loads, 6 pictures are randomly chosen from an array (w/ data from db)

all of this works fine. But what I want to achieve is that when a ImageButton is pressed, it gets the CURRENT ImageUrl. But when I do this, the page loads again and another ImageUrl is set.

For example, let's say ImageButton 1 has "picture1.png" as ImageUrl.
When I press the button, I want to save "picture1.png" as a value, before it changes to "picture5.png" in the page_load.

how do I do this, what's the best way to fix this?

I don't really have code I could show, because I've been doing "trial and error" and I want to start from scratch. I just want to save the current ImageUrl before it changes.

EDIT:

The following code is the last I've tried. For all ImageButtons, I have one ClickEvent (ImageClick) and all ImageButtons have a pre-set CommandName (defined this in the source code)

```
protected void ImageClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)sender;
        string url= "";
        switch (imgbtn.CommandName)
            {
                case "imgbtn1":
                    url = imgbtn.ImageUrl;
                    break;
                case "imgbtn2":
                    url = imgbtn.ImageUrl;
                    break;
                case "imgbtn3":
                    url = imgbtn.ImageUrl;
                    break;
                case "imgbtn4":
                    url = imgbtn.ImageUrl;
                    break;
                case "imgbtn5":
                    url = imgbtn.ImageUrl;
                    break;
                case "imgbtn6":
                    url = imgbtn.ImageUrl;
                    break;
        }
        Debug.Print(url);
    }
```

Comment: post some code what you tried ??

Comment: There are many question for both WebForms (how to store state of the form) and ASP.Net MVC (how to pass data from view to next action)... You need to realize that `img` that unlike input controls does not post data back by itself - and figure out that you need post state of your `img` controls yourself.